# Why does a form submit only refresh the page when I turn on codeigniter caching?

Tags: caching, codeigniter

probably a noob question but I am not sure what is going on. Here is the function from the controller...

```
    function product ($product_id = NULL)
{


    if ($this->input->post())
    {
        $pcs = array();
        $pcs[] = $this->input->post('product_id');
        $pcs[] = $this->input->post('styles');
        $build = implode('-', $pcs);

        redirect('seatcovers/configure/'.$build);

    }
    elseif ($this->_checkID('id','products',$product_id))
    {

        $data['product'] = $this->model_products->getProductRow($product_id);
        $data['styles'] = $this->model_products->getStyles($product_id);
        $data['images'] = $this->model_products->getImages($product_id);



        $tags['title'] = 'title';

        $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('language').'/includes/view_header',$tags);
        $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('language').'/products/view_product',$data);
        $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('language').'/includes/view_footer');    
    }
    else {
        redirect('seatcovers');
    }

}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Does caching not work when their is a form?

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question with the code you provided. Can you instead ask your question in a more abstract way? And provide more abstract code?

Comment: I agree with Yasser. Is it safe to assume that based on your question, you've verified that it does indeed work without caching? Perhaps turning on error messages or code profiling would help you trackdown whatever is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, caching is done on URI level means, when a URL is cached in Codeigniter then it will display the cached page and will not execute your controller.